# Limit USB access for certain user

Tags: debian, usb, users, udev

I want to setup a laptop for a party room that will play music. I successfully installed Debian on the machine and created a "party" user. All guests should will be allowed to choose music from the library and to put it in the playlist. Now this laptop is quite old and therefore has limited disk capacity and so I bought a SD card to store my whole music library. But as my music contains lots of files from Amazon which are watermarked with my Amazon account, I want to ensure that no one can simply take the SD card or copy my music to an own device.

Still, I would generally allow guests to attach their own USB sticks to bring their music.

My planned strategy would be to

- encrypt the SD card by BitLocker which I successfully managed. When I insert the SD card to the laptop, the key is read and the card is accessible by Debian and
- block any other USB or SD storage device for writing that could be used for copying files. This is what I  was not able to realize.

Do you think this is a reasonable strategy to realize my goal? Would you have a hint how to realize b)? I think that udev could be used, but I am not familiar with this tool...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Seen this https://superuser.com/questions/196764/auto-mount-usb-drives-read-only ? And, generally, search for auto-mounting removable devices read only. You, as admin, could then re-mount anything read-write if you desire so.

Comment: Thanks. Well, is there any chance to make this user-specific in udev?

Comment: Take a backup of the SDcard - its not a very reliable storage medium.

Comment: I'll do. But how can I manage to make the SD card access user-specific?